# Is there a descriptive term for the demonstrative pronoun "that" which conveys the underlying notion of pointing to something *out there*?

Tags: terminology, semantics

I have read (somewhere) that the demonstrative pronoun describes something outside or away from the observer and that this has a descriptive term, philosophically not as a grammar term. *That* out there.

Comment: Are you referrung to distal diexis?

Comment: _That, those, thither, thence, then, them_ are all distal deictics from the same PIE root. _This_ and _these_ are proximals from the same root. Read [Fillmore's Deixis Lectures](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html) to see how it works.

Comment: Yes! That is it. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis